# ArchLinux - yaourt: save updatelog?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

When I do `yaourt -Syu` sometimes there is such a long log in the console so that the buffer gets full and some information is lost. As the information is important sometimes I´d like to save everything that´s logged by yaourt/pacman in a file.

Doing `yaourt -Syu > file` does save things to file, but then you cannot see what´s going on in the console. Is it possible to have both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, pipe it to `tee`

From the `tee` man page:

```
NAME
   tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

SYNOPSIS
   tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
   Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
```

So your command should be `yaourt -Syu | tee yaourt.log`

Answer (score 1):

I am normally most interested about what ultimately is installed so I just look at the  pacman log located at `/var/log/pacman.log`. All pacman output is there so you can see if there were any errors or important warnings.