# Arch Linux: colors from terminal in bash script?

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, arch-linux

## In addition to [ArchLinux - yaourt: save updatelog?](https://superuser.com/questions/381183/archlinux-yaourt-save-updatelog)

With `tee` I am able to get the output at a file and at the terminal at the same time.
But when I execute `yaourt -Syu | tee yaourt.log` in a bash file (which is executed in a terminal) the output of yaourt does not have the usual **colors** (no colors). Also (sure) when opening the text file you cannot see colors.

- Is it possible to still see the color formatting of yaourt when executing the above command via a bash script?
- Is it possible to see the saved text in the same color formatting later again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to display the color formatting of `yaourt` in the terminal and to save the output (with color codes) at the same time in a file is to use the yaourt `color` option :

```
yaourt -Syua --color | tee yaourt.log
```

To display the log file use :

```
cat yaourt.log
```

instead of a text editor, because the color codes make the log unreadable

Comment: Great, that works!